# aws rekognition error 'InvalidImageFormatException'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

rekognition.detectFaces method return an error `InvalidImageFormatException`.
Cheack method's document [aws rekognition](http://%5B1%5D:%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/rekognition/latest/dg/API_DetectFaces.html). I think it's simply format problem so changed image to jpg, png, jpeg.But error doesn't change.

Is anything I can do for fixed?

here is aws lambda function

```js
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const rekognition = new aws.Rekognition();

exports.handler = async(event) => {
  var imageBytes = new Buffer.from(event.body, "base64"); //event.body from local's form
  const params = {
    Attributes: ["DEFAULT"],
    Image: {
      Bytes: imageBytes,
    },
  };
 const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

 rekognition.detectFaces(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err);
    reject(err);
  }
  else console.log(data);
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: data,
  };
  resolve(response);
  });
 });
return promise;
};
```

cloudWatchLog

```
2021-01-10T10:35:53.666Z    275e6ac7-058f-4100-8dbb-914c515d3d4d    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "errorType": "InvalidImageFormatException",
    "errorMessage": "Request has invalid image format",
    "code": "InvalidImageFormatException",
    "message": "Request has invalid image format",
    "time": "2021-01-10T10:35:53.591Z",
    "requestId": "8a27e681-2a13-473c-b485-dad8c1d9a486",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 98.6486455321961,
    "stack": [
        "InvalidImageFormatException: Request has invalid image format",
        "    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
    ]
}
```

I checked I can use my images in rekognition console.Working!
I checked whether my images(PNG,JPG etc) can use Lambda function.
It's from same html file, same code, same form,just changed lambda code.
Error not come up, I can upload to S3.

I also checked `event`info, for rekognition(written,up) and for S3(written,down).Result almost are same.

What can I for get result from rekognition?

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3 = new AWS.S3()

const handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  
  let requestBody = Buffer.from(event.body, 'base64')
  console.log(event);
  s3.putObject({
    Body: requestBody,
    Bucket: 'myBacket', 
    ContentType: 'image/JPG',
    Key: 'test.JPG'
  }).promise()
   
    .then((result) => {
      callback(null, {
        body: JSON.stringify(result),
        statusCode: 200
      })
    })
    
    .catch((err) => {
      callback(err, {
        body: JSON.stringify(err),
        statusCode: 500
      })
})
}

module.exports = { handler }
```

Comment: Try running the image using the AWS Management Console and see if you still get this issue. Then you will know for sure if issue is with the image you are using.

Comment: I tried.I understood my images' issue.But, I don't know `InvalidImageFormatException` is meant for.